# VS Code error Enoent: no such directory, lstat'/snap/code'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got an error when launch VS Code, I tried to to stop every extension to check if error fill gone.. but not. It's Ubuntu machine
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUJTo.png)

Comment: It happen when I start the program and also when I want to check for updates,
I delete completely the entire package of VS Code, and I reinstall it again..But same think. no idea where it come from

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It concerns users using VSCode with snap on Ubunutu.
VSCode is looking in the wrong directory.

The problem was reported here : [github.com/Microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/63716)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65095#issuecomment-447658666), the problem may be fixed temporarily by running:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/vscode /snap/code
```